# MongoDB. Как взять поля с разных колекций

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Здравствуйте.

Хочу написать агрегатку или же методом `lookup` получить данные с разных колекций. 
Но не знаю как)

Допустим

Колекция `users`

```
{
    _id: 951ddd10834e28097f2d67d5,
    name: "aladin",
    phone: 123123,
}
```

Колекция `items`

```
{
    _id: 596wde31434e755097f2w22e4,
    title: "asd",
    description: "sub asd"
    author: 951ddd10834e28097f2d67d5   // id такой же как и в aladin
}
```

Хочу получить:

```
{
        title: "asd",
        description: "sub asd",
        author: "aladin"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.users.aggregate([
{
  $lookup:
    {
      from: "items",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "951ddd10834e28097f2d67d5",
      as: "items"
    }
},
{
  $unwind: "$items"
},
{ 
  $project : { title : 1 , description: 1, author: 1, _id: 0 }
])
```